# ASP.NET MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can I see one example that would make this piece of code compile?

```
    public IEnumerable<RouteBase> Routes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Route>()
            {
                new Route(...)
            }
        }
    }
```

What would you do if `RouteCollection.MapRoute()` didn't exist?

I'm trying to put my Controller in charge of mapping routes, not Global.asax.cs. `public IEnumerable<RouteBase> Routes` is a member of my Controller. If the Controller is responsible for a Route, it's a bad idea to decouple the Route by using a separate hardcoded URL in `routes.MapRoute()` in `Global.asax.cs`.

In response to Mr. Harvey:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Include(new RootController());
    }
}

public static class RouteCollectionExtension
{
    public static RouteCollection Include(this RouteCollection routes, IRoutedController controller)
    {
        foreach (var route in controller.Routes)
        {
            routes.Add(route);
        }

        return routes;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class RootController : Controller, IRoutedController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteBase> Routes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Route>()
            {
                new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}", ...?!?)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a chicken and egg problem? How is the controller method going to set up routes if it never executes, (the routing engine executes controller methods, so it needs at least one existing route to do that)?

Comment: Perhaps. :)        #                  #

Comment: Don't know if that edit was directed at me or not. The Controller is not responsible for the routes, the routing engine is. I admire your tenacity, but you still haven't explained how you're going to execute the controller method in the first place, so you can set up some routes, if the routing engine has no predefined routes, and therefore no way to execute the controller method.

Answer (score 2):

The one line that scared me in this post was the following

> I'm trying to put my Controller in
>   charge of mapping routes

The whole idea behind asp.net mvc is clear seperation of concerns. This will kill the testability of the controller as the controller isn't just controlling anymore but meddling with the routes.